# How to config a HTTP Request Method GET with JSON BODY in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm facing the issue while writing the scenario in JMeter. It's API using `GET` Method and requires `JSON BODY`.

It's very easy if the method is `POST/PUT`. But I don't know how to do with method GET. I tried: Add `HTTP Header Manager` with `Content-Type:application/json`, but nothing help.

As I know, using `BODY` with `GET` request is the not the good way, but the developer team has implemented like that, and it can be worked with `curl`.

So I would like to know can we config this in JMeter or not? and How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact sending request body with HTTP GET request is not supported by [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) and hence in JMeter, you should be able to send a GET request with JSON body using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following code (assumes [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language):

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

public  class HttpGetWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "GET";

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
}

def client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
def getRequest = new HttpGetWithBody();
getRequest.setURI(new URL("http://example.com").toURI());
def json = "{\"employees\":[\n" +
        "    {\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\":\"Doe\"},\n" +
        "    {\"firstName\":\"Anna\", \"lastName\":\"Smith\"},\n" +
        "    {\"firstName\":\"Peter\", \"lastName\":\"Jones\"}\n" +
        "]}";
def body = new StringEntity(json, "application/json", "UTF-8");
getRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
getRequest.setEntity(body);
def response = client.execute(getRequest);
def result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
log.info(result);
```

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for more information on using JSR223 test elements and groovy language and scripting best practices.

Comment: You saved me one more time, how can I say thank you. I just read your answer, not trying net, but I think it will work. One question, in your code, the way to define json is a bit difficult, I wonder can we use **JsonBuilder** instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, any way to populate a JSON payload will play

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported bug in JMeter for this https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60358 and looks like the fix is on the way. Hopefully this issue would be fixed soon.