# JMeter: How to send GET request with body data?

Tags: jmeter

I want perform load test on my Elasticsearch deployment. `_search` API of Elasticsearch expects body data with search request as documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search.html).

However I see that body data is sent empty when I send GET request. I could verify it from "view results tree" as well as from logs on my server. Is it not allowed to send Body Data in GET quest or am I doing something wrong? I am using JMeter 3.0 r1743807. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSmfa.png) also attached.

```
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="One-Dimension aggregation" enabled="true">
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true</boolProp>
  <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
      <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
        <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">{&#xd;
    &quot;query&quot;: {&#xd;
      &quot;filtered&quot;: {&#xd;
        &quot;query&quot;: {&#xd;
          &quot;query_string&quot;: {&#xd;
            &quot;query&quot;: &quot;+_exists_:category_list&quot;,&#xd;
            &quot;analyze_wildcard&quot;: true&#xd;
          }&#xd;
        }&#xd;
      }&#xd;
    },&#xd;
    &quot;size&quot;: 0,&#xd;
    &quot;aggs&quot;: {&#xd;
      &quot;2&quot;: {&#xd;
        &quot;terms&quot;: {&#xd;
          &quot;field&quot;: &quot;category_list.raw&quot;,&#xd;
          &quot;size&quot;: 20,&#xd;
          &quot;order&quot;: {&#xd;
            &quot;_count&quot;: &quot;desc&quot;&#xd;
          }&#xd;
        }&#xd;
      }&#xd;
    }&#xd;
  }</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
    </collectionProp>
  </elementProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/-*kibana*/_search/</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
</HTTPSamplerProxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall [answering similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506372/how-to-config-a-http-request-method-get-with-json-body-in-jmeter/)

Shortly: you cannot do it using JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, but it is possible via scripting. I would recommend getting familiarized with the [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article prior to implementing the solution from the above answer.

Comment: Looks like BeanShell or JSR223 are only possibilities right now. However, I submitted a bug on JMeter for this https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60358 and the fix is on the way. Hopefully this issue will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Its fixed in the latest [jMeter ver. 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi). see [bugzilla #60358](http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60358)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to JMeter+ElasticSearch **POST** and **GET** requests on `/index-name/_search` are equivalent.

At least for me.

Below screenshot from Insomnia:

[image]